# Знак вопроса и восклицательный знак с многоточием

Tags: пунктуация

Задался вот тут вопросом, как правильно оборванные слова писать со знаками вопросов и восклицания. Если вопросительный и восклицательные знаки съедают одну точку в многоточии ?.. , !.. , то как же правильно будет в случае оборванного слова вопроса или восклицания типа Чт..? , Чт?.., или же Прекра..! и далее в общем, в интернете что-то про это ничего не нашел.

Comment: Не надо знака, прав М_Г: И мертвые губы. Шепнули: «Грена...».

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, если речь оборвалась, то не было возможности уловить интонацию. Значит, бессмысленно ставить вопросительные и  восклицательные знаки. Вот как у Михалкова:

Уже крокодил
У Фомы за спиной.
Уже крокодил
Поперхнулся Фомой:
Из пасти у зверя
Торчит голова.

До берега
Ветер доносит слова:
— Непра...
Я не ве... —
Аллигатор вздохнул
И, сытый,
В зеленую воду нырнул.

Answer (score 1):

**-По...подпоручик Алехин, ваше бла...- дрожащим голосом представился врангелевец.

-Бегите вон за ротмистром! - оборвав его на полуслове, приказал...**
Миссия в Париже    И.Болгарин

**-Дала бы девке образование закончить хоре...хоре... - не с первого раза, с раскачки берет мудреное слово дед, - хо-ре-огра-фи-чес-кое...**
Жизнь прожить   В.Астафьев

**Дополнение**

Не соглашусь, что в оборванном слове невозможно уловить интонации. Это может быть почти законченный крик, плач, смертельная боль или надрывный вопрос.
 Очень часто такой прием применяется при употреблении нецензурных фраз.  Слово не проговаривается до конца, но его интонация и смысл всем понятны. В этих случаях использование восклицательного или вопросительного знака просто необходимо.

-Какой эпитет подходит?  **Зло..!** -Она развела руками. -Сам додумывай!
  -А как ты хочешь, чтобы я тебя назвал?  **Б..?**

Comment: Римма, пробелы сделайте!

Comment: Я недавно присоединилась к вашему сайту. Приношу извинения за возможные ошибки, я только учусь.

Comment: (1) Замена слов многоточием - особый случай, не прописанный в справочниках. (2) Сочетание многоточия с вопр. и воскл. знаками в принципе возможно. Правила требуют ставить вопр. и воскл. знак вместо первой точки. (3) Это не относится к случаю, когда речь неожиданно оборвалась. По-моему, здесь ставится только троеточие.

Comment: Где Вы нашли у Панкеева многоточие? **Не-е-т!! - снова вырвалось из груди, и неведомая сила подняла меня еще на полметра.** http://books.rusf.ru/unzip/add-on/xussr_mr/pankei11.htm?3/4

Comment: @М_Г Посмотрела Вашу ссылку.  Да, Вы правы!  К сожалению, свой источник теперь найти не могу,  поэтому подкорректировала ответ.